# Row Count section is highlighted but unclear

Tags: vba

The section that says: `RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row`, is highlighted in red and yellow when I select debug. I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean.

```
Sub DQAnalysis()

    Worksheets("DQ Analysis").Activate
    
    Range("A1").Value = "DAQ0 (Ticker: DQ)"
    
    'Create a header row
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "Year"
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
    Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"
    
    Worksheets("2018").Activate
    
    'set initial volume to zero
    totalVolume = 0
    
    Dim startingPrice As Double
    Dim endingPrice As Double
    
    'find the number of rows to loop over
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row
    
    'loop over all the rows
    For i = 2 To RowCount
    
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "DQ" Then

            'increase totalVolume by the value in the current row
            totalVolume = totalVolume + Cells(i, 8).Value

        End If
    
        If Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> "DQ" And Cells(i, 1).Value = "DQ" Then
    
        endingPrice = Cells(i, 6).Value
    
        End If
        
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> "DQ" And Cells(i, 1).Value = "DQ" Then

            endingPrice = Cells(i, 6).Value

        End If
    
    Next i
    
    Worksheets("DQ Analysis").Activate
    Cells(4, 1).Value = 2018
    Cells(4, 2).Value = totalVolume
    Cells(4, 3).Value = (endingPrice / startingPrice) - 1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The part `End(x1Up)` is the letter L not the number 1, like that `End(xlUp)`

Comment: Thank you so much for this feedback. I noticed after applying the correction, this section remains highlighted in yellow.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: A yellow highlight is how the VBA IDE shows the current line the program has stopped on. The red text is a compilation error on that line (e.g. bad syntax).

Answer (score 0):

This line calculates the last row's count, you can use this code:

```
RowCount = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
```

It means select "A100000" cell and go up to find a cell that not null. It shows the last row of our table on A column.